# Could not load file or assembly 'interop.scripting, version=1.0.0.0,

Tags: vb.net, vba

I am running my project in debug mode and it work fine, 
but when i tried to compile it shows this error: what does this error mean?

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (3/27/2013 @ 2:22:26 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Documents and Settings\nsbadmin\Desktop\antiSpam.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NIDECSUBIC\nsbadmin
LOG: DisplayName = antiSpam.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Documents and Settings/nsbadmin/Desktop/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : antiSpam, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using machine configuration file from      c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Documents and Settings/nsbadmin/Desktop/en/antiSpam.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Documents and Settings/nsbadmin/Desktop/en/antiSpam.resources/antiSpam.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Documents and Settings/nsbadmin/Desktop/en/antiSpam.resources.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Documents and Settings/nsbadmin/Desktop/en/antiSpam.resources/antiSpam.resources.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are failed when trying to find a file resources. In VS, change it properties to be embeded into your exe file.

Comment: where can i change the properties to be embedded in exe file?

Comment: From solution explorer, Right click on your project's resources file (usually in Properies subfolder). Choose option  Embed . . .